# issue with border radius

Tags: html, css

I'm new to html/css and I know this has been asked many times before but the answers didn't help / could not comprehend them. I assume it has something do to with the way I arranged the page in on the html side. Thanks

```css
div.text {
  color: yellow;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 6em;
  text-align: center;
}

div.img {
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 44px background-color:#555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Let Go</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Lore Ipsum?</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.globaldots.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/ddos_attack-768x550.jpg" alt="">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TWo mistakes: The selector has to be `div.img img` to affect the image itself, and there was a semicollon missing:

```css
div.text {
  color: yellow;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 6em;
  text-align: center;
}

div.img img {
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 44px;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Let Go</title>
</head>


<body>
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Lore Ipsum?</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.globaldots.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/ddos_attack-768x550.jpg" alt="">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I thought I was selecting the image properly since the "opacity" attribute worked on it. Thanks !

Comment: well, the image is inside the div, so an opacity on the container div will look the same as an opacity on the div as long as the div doesn't have a background on its own.

Answer (score 1):

Do the radius on the image, not the element that contains it. Also, you are missing a semi-color before you set the background color

```css
div.text {
  color: yellow;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: blue;
  line-height: 6em;
  text-align: center;
}

div img {
  opacity: 0.3;
  border-radius: 44px; 
  background-color:#555;
}
```

```html
  <div class="text">
    <h1>Lore Ipsum?</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="img">
    <img src="http://www.globaldots.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/ddos_attack-768x550.jpg" alt="">

  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I did not miss the semicolon, I think it got removed when I pressed "tidy up" before posting the code.